# Cohomology with Coefficients in the sheaf of distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

It just occurred to me that one could form the sheaf of distributions $F$ on any manifold where for an open set $U$ we have $F(U)$ is the algebra of distributions on $U.$ What does cohomology with coefficients in $F$ represent? Is there a good interpretation using differential forms or differential operators?

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me whether (Schwarz) distributions can even be _restricted_ to an open subset...

Comment: @ZhenLin You read this as Schwartz distributions? Isn't the more typical use of the term "distribution on a manifold" meaning, well, distribution as defined in any differential geometry text? Since the condition on the subspaces of the tangent space is local, I'd guess these do form a sheaf. On the other hand, I'm not sure in what sense they form an "algebra" so ...

Comment: Oh, _that_ thing. In my mind that's just a special kind of vector subbundle.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ugh, but why can't we [restrict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Restriction) a Schwartz distribution to an open set? Even more, it constitutes a fine sheaf, so are sheaves of currents, which forms a fine resolution of the constant sheaf $\mathbb R$, say.

Comment: @FrankScience can you elaborate on the last sentence? What is a sheaf of currents? What is the fine resolution of $\mathbb R$ you're talking about?

Comment: @Exterior Suppose $\xi\colon E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, then we can define sheaf of distribution cross-sections of $\xi$, see Gunning's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*, section 6 (some terms are archaic). Especially, consider exterior products of the cotangent bundle, we obtain a sequence of vector bundles, and we can consider the corresponding sheaves.

Comment: @Exterior The fine resolution is similar to $0\to\mathbb R\to\Omega^0\to\Omega^1\to\Omega^2\to\dotsb$, where $\Omega^p$ is the sheaf of $p$-forms, replacing $\Omega^p$'s with corresponding sheaves of distributions of cross-sections.

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't even know if you're still interested in this year-old question or what, but in case anyone else finds it via some web search and wants an answer, I'll post some thoughts I had on the question:

First of all, it's apparent that a [distribution on the manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28differential_geometry%29) $M$ restricts to a distribution on the submanifold $U \subset M$; just pull the distribution back along the inclusion. With a little checking one verifies that the sheaf axioms are satisfied and we obtain a sheaf $\mathcal{S}$ of (sets of) distributons on $M$.

The problem is that there's no convenient/natural way to give this the structure of a sheaf of abelian groups. We could use the [Whitney sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Operations_on_vector_bundles) of bundles and pass from the monoid structure thus determined to the [Grothendieck group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group), but this employs the external direct sum of vector spaces pointwise and doesn't reflect the key fact that distributions are subbundles of $TM$.

If we instead take the inner sum of vector subspaces and attempt to define a sum of bundles by applying the inner sum pointwise, we run into a different problem. We get a commutative monoid out of the collection of vector subspaces of a given space with inner sum as the operation, surely. But, when trying to pass to the Grothendieck group, we find that the group obtained is trivial! Letting $V$ be any vector space and $M_1, M_2, N_1, N_2$ be any vector subspaces, we can set $K = M_1 + M_2 + N_1 + N_2$
and then we have

$$M_1 + N_2 + K = M_2 + N_1 + K.$$

So the Grothendieck group consists of exactly one equivalence class, containing all ordered pairs of vector subspaces of $V$.

Of course, there might still be some way to impose algebraic structure on $\mathcal{S}$, but I have to imagine it would be quite contrived.