# What are some properties of the sheaf of distributions?

Tags: distribution-theory, sheaf-theory

In a course on measure theory, the lecturer proved that distributions (on a locally convex space I think) form a sheaf $\mathcal D$. He isn't interested in sheaves, so he didn't elaborate. Afterwards, I looked online for material on this sheaf, but didn't really find any information about it. On MSE, there is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/cohomology-with-coefficients-in-the-sheaf-of-distributions) regarding sheaf cohomology w.r.t to $\mathcal D$, which looks cool but is beyond me.

What are some interesting properties of $\mathcal D$? Is it soft, flabby, or fine? What else?

Comment: Distributions form a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-module, so $\mathcal{D}$ is a soft, hence flabby, sheaf.

Comment: @Roland do you mean $\mathcal D$ is *fine* and therefore soft?

Comment: @Roland soft hence flabby, should it be rather the converse and also I don't think the sheaf of distribution is flabby, right ? however hyperfunction sheaf is